# Iterate through all SimpleTextBox's

Tags: java, class, gwt, object, loops

Is it possible to iterate trough all 'instances' of a specific class?  Ive been looking around, and came up with:

```
        for (Field field : SimpleCheckBox.class.getFields()) {
        System.out.println(field.getName());
    }
```

I want to go through all the fields, and implement some functions on them, without having to individually select them all. The code above gives the error :

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method getFields() is undefined for the type Class
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, that error is strange, you should be able to compile that. Maybe it is a GWT issue with not supporting the method, but in plain old java it would work.

But it would not work as you expect. It would give you the fields ("attributes") defined in the class, not the instances of the class themselves (fields in the UI concept is not the same than fields in the OP concept).

So far, there is no easy way to get all current instances of a class.

If what you want is (as it looks like) get all checkboxes in one container and do some operation, maybe what you want to do is to retrieve all the **Components** of the container and check them with the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, will iterate through the components in the container. +1 :)

Comment: Most reflection isn't supported in GWT, as that would require compiling in all possible types/fields/methods, so the compiler can't remove a lot of code. `java.lang.Class` in GWT doesnt support `getFields`, among others. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation for more detail on JRE support, specifically the details about `Class`.